# Aligning all UL LI elements in one line in center with applying CSS only to the UL?

Tags: html, css

How would you make all of the `<li>` items in a `<ul>` element to be displayed in a line, and how would you center that entire list on the page? You must apply your CSS directly to the `<ul>` element itself, you cannot use a parent element.

I tried with `display:inline-flex` but then you can't align the `<li>` items in center so any possible way to do this?

Here is my Fiddle but I cannot align the `<li>` in center as :
**https://jsfiddle.net/pymg30yr/**

Comment: `display:inline-block` on `li` and `text-align:center` to `ul` ?

Comment: @Akshay : You cannot apply style to a parent element..! Isn't `li` a parent element?

Comment: @Akshay : You can only apply style directly to `<ul>` only no style to be applied to `li` elements..!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem with `inline-flex` is that your `ul` will take the width of its content so you cannot center the items inside (as there is no space either side)

In order to fix this, just make the `ul` `flex` and then add `justify-content:center`:

```css
ul {
    padding:0; 
    margin:0;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>Link 1</li>
 <li>Link 2</li>
 <li>Link 3</li>
 <li>Link 4</li>
 <li>Link 5</li>
 <li>Link 6</li>
 <li>Link 7</li>
 <li>Link 8</li>
 <li>Link 9</li>
 <li>Link 10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks , Works in Firefox , chrome and IE browser...!

Answer (score -1):

html

```
<ul>
  <li>a list item </li>
  <li>a loooooooooooooooooooong list item </li>
  <li>another list item</li>
</ul>
```

css

```
ul {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

demo
http://jsfiddle.net/fNFYr/467/